# Meaning of convergence for a double infinite serie. How do we sum two index "at the same time"

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, definition

In [this](https://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Ecmart07/fubini.pdf) document is expressed the Fubini theorem for series.

It is said that if $a_{jk}$ is a doubly indexed finite sequence that verifies:

$$\sum_{j,k} |a_{jk}|<\infty$$

Then, $\sum_{j,k} a_{jk}$ exists, and:

$$\sum_{j,k} a_{jk}=\sum_j \sum_k a_{jk} = \sum_k \sum_j a_{jk}$$

What I am struggling to understand is: what does $\sum_{j,k} |a_{jk}|<\infty$ even mean? Indeed, I  know what it means to have a serie $\sum_n a_n$ that either converge or diverge. By extension, I know what it means that $\sum_j \sum_k u_{jk}$ converge or not (I first do the summation of what there is inside, then I sum with the outter sum and I check if the thing is finite or not). But in $\sum_{j,k} |a_{jk}|$ we sum "at the same time" on both index. What does convergence mean in this context?

Comment: For an arbitrary index set $I$ (countable or uncountable) and for a family $(a_i)_{i \in I}$ of non-negative real numbers, by definition, $$\sum_{i \in I} a_i = \sup \left\{ \sum_{i \in K} a_i \ \mid \ K \subset I \text{ finite} \right\}. $$ This is exactly the definition of the Lebesgue integral with respect to the counting measure. The definition for the sum of arbitrary real numbers is, again, exactly the one as for the Lebesgue integral.

Comment: Think of the index set as the grid $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ to gain some intuition. The first expression sums across each point on the grid. The second expression separately sums each vertical line, then sums those totals. The third separately sums each horizontal line, then sums those totals.

Comment: @William. Thank you for your comment. Yes I understand and agree with this, but there might have an infinite number of way to sum "across each point of the grid". Does the sentence "$\sum_{jk} a_{jk}$ converges" is just a way to say that whatever choice you use to make this summation it would converge *and* give the same result? If this is the case then $\sum_{jk} a_{jk}=\sum_j \sum_k a_{jk}=\sum_k \sum_j a_{jk}$ is a straightforward application of the definition of $\sum_{jk} a_{jk}$, hence I am not sure to understand.

Comment: The actual ordering of summation in $jk$ depends on the specific indexing set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$I$ denotes a countable set (possible $\mathbb{N}$ for a simple series, or also $\mathbb{N}^2$ if you have a double sum).

The family of **positive** reals $\left(u_{i}\right)_{i \in I}$ is said to be summable if the set of all the sums $\sum_{i \in F} u_{i}$, where $F$ describes the set of finite parts of $I$ has an upper-bound. In this case, the upper bound of this set is called the sum of the family $\left(u_{i}\right)_{i \in I}$ i.e $\sum_{i \in I} u_{i}$ . If the family is not summable, we agree that its sum is $+\infty$. If the terms are of different sign, it doesn't make sense to talk about the sum of the series because depending on the order of summation it can change the result.

However the definition given above is not really easy to used in practice. We have a more practical result. Let $\left(u_{m, n}\right)_{(m, n) \in \mathbb{N}^{2}}$ be a family of complex (or reals) numbers. The following assertions are equivalent:

- the family $\left(u_{m, n}\right)_{(m, n) \in \mathbb{N}^{2}}$ is summable;
- for any integer $n$, the series $\sum_{m}\left|u_{m, n}\right|$ converges, and the series $\sum_{n}\left(\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\left|u_{m, n}\right|\right)$ is convergent.

In this case, we have equality of sums:
$$
\sum_{(m, n) \in \mathbb{N}^{2}} u_{m, n}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{+\infty} u_{m, n}=\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} u_{m, n} .
$$

Thus if the family is summable, you can sum in the order you want it doesn't matter.

Note that the question can already arise in the case of a one-dimensional summation, because if a series converge but not absolutely then by rearranging the terms when summing a series we can obtain any value (finite or infinite): this is the Riemann rearrangement theorem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I understand.

Answer (score 2):

Let $E$ be a Banach space and let $I, J$ be a countable sets. (You may think of $E=\mathbb{K}$ for simplicity.)

> Suppose $(a_n)\in E^{\mkern1mu\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence. Recall the following:
>
> - We say that the series $\sum_na_n$ is **absolutely convergent** if $\sum_n|a_n|$ converges. In this case we write $\sum_n|a_n|<\infty$.
> - We say that the series $\sum_na_n$ is **unconditionally convergent** if it converges and if every rearrangement converges to the same value.
> - Every absolutely convergent series is unconditionally convergent.
>
> Suppose now that $(a_i)\in E^I$.
>
> - We say that $(a_i)$ is **summable** and write $\sum_i |a_i|<\infty$ if there exists a bijection $\sigma:\mathbb{N}\to I$ such that $\sum_n |a_{\sigma(n)}|<\infty$.
> - In this case, for every bijection $\sigma:\mathbb{N}\to I$ we have $\sum_n |a_{\sigma(n)}|<\infty$; hence for every bijection $\sigma:\mathbb{N}\to I$ the series $\sum_n a_{\sigma(n)}$ converges to a value independent of $\sigma$, which we denote by $\sum_{i\in I} a_i$.

As mentioned in the comments, we may consider the discrete measure space $(I, \mathcal{P}(I))$ equipped with the counting measure  $\mkern2mu\#:\mathcal{P}(I)\to[0,\infty]$. Note that every $(a_i)\in E^I$ is measurable and that $(a_i)$ is Lebesgue integrable if and only if $\sum_i |a_i|<\infty$. In this case we have
$$ \int_I a_i\,d\#=\sum_{i\in I} a_i.$$
Using this observation, Fubini's theorem for series follows at once.

> **Theorem.** Let $(a_{ij})\in E^{I\times J}$ be summable. Then the following holds:
>
> - $\sum_j |a_{ij}|<\infty$ for all $i\in I$ and $\sum_i |a_{ij}|<\infty$ for all $j\in J$.
> - $\sum_i\bigl\lvert\sum_{j\in J} a_{ij}\bigr\rvert<\infty$ and $\sum_j\bigl\lvert\sum_{i\in I} a_{ij}\bigr\rvert<\infty$.
> - We have $\sum_{(i,j)\in I\times J} a_{ij}=\sum_{i\in I}\sum_{j\in J} a_{ij}=\sum_{j\in J}\sum_{i\in I} a_{ij}$.

Lastly we note that a double sequence $(a_{mn})\in E^{\mkern1mu\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}}$ is summable if and only if $$\sup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\,\sum_{m=0}^k\sum_{n=0}^k |a_{mn}|<\infty.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I accepted the other because I am not very familiar with measure theory even though your answer looked pretty nice! I upvoted